# Convert ParIterable to Iterable

Tags: scala

This is a very short question.

I have a `ParIterable` collection and I want to convert it "back" into `Iterable`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corresponding [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterable.html) says:

> Methods:
>
> ```
> def seq: Sequential
> def par: Repr
> ```
>
> produce the sequential or parallel implementation of the collection,
>   respectively. Method par just returns a reference to this parallel
>   collection. Method seq is efficient - it will not copy the elements.
>   Instead, it will create a sequential version of the collection using
>   the same underlying data structure. Note that this is not the case for
>   sequential collections in general - they may copy the elements and
>   produce a different underlying data structure.
>
> The combination of methods toMap, toSeq or toSet along with par and
>   seq is a flexible way to change between different collection types.

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the companion object documentation ( http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterable$.html ) the whole time. OK

Comment: +1 for the motivated explanation with reference to doc material

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just call `.seq`. Example:

```
scala> val x = Iterable(1,2,3).par
x: scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable[Int] = ParVector(1, 2, 3)

scala> x.seq
res6: Iterable[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```